# jQuery trigger on image load (hidden image)

Tags: jquery, triggers, load, background-image, image

OK, so I've heard that JS cannot trigger events on CSS background image load. So, what I've seen some people suggest, is to trigger the event on an img tag load. But you obviously would need to hide this image so it doesn't get displayed?

Do you need to put this image somewhere on your page and then do something like: display:none css?

Otherwise it would obviously be a nice big image you don't want to see...

I would have thought most half decent browsers wouldn't load an image if it was display:none; . Or could JS just load the image into the cache, with HTML being completely unaware of it?

Am I wrong?... If so, it is one of those rare moments in life where being wrong is awesome.

Can't wait for HTML6. Also can't wait for nobody to support it as usual, and then be another cynical idiot that bangs on about it for another 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

Display none could actually not load the image at all, which nullifies exactly what you want to accomplish.

You can easily add an image to the 'cache'.

```
var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.onload = function(){
        // What you want to do!
    };
    myImage.src = 'myimage.png';
```

Comment: additionally, will this stop a further HTTP request for the background image? Seems like it wouldn't, but would be interested to hear your experience.

Comment: Cross browser: Can't remember it not working on any modern graphical browser. And if it will stop the other http request depends on the browser. Some browsers are very efficient/smart and others are not. I have never tested this. It will at least use cache if available.

Comment: sounds good to me. Can't believe that old school stuff works for this application. So good. Perfect answer and +1. Great clean code by the way.

Comment: hmm, seems this only works on 1st page load. jQuery's .load() for images is a little more complex because of browser cache. If the image is cached, you're going to have trouble with this. Now I know this officially not a quick fix. Definitely not. Stupidly complex for a common problem. A quick thank you to all those idiots who make browsers and software that can't handle common interface needs.

Comment: What is the exact issue? Or what are you trying to get done? Wrap the image.load in a document.load and you would never get a function that fires too early. But of course, maybe your usage case is entirely different than any I've had.